# Sending POST request to page with multiple forms

Tags: c#, forms, post

I have found [this great class](http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx) for sending POST request to a webpage. Now I tried it on a test page with single form and it works. But now I would like to do a POST request to a page, that has multiple forms on the same page. Is it possible to select specific form, if it is defined with name?

For example, like this:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" target="_parent">
...
</form>
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="login" target="_top" class="login">
// This is the form that I want to post data
...
<input value="Go" type="submit" id="input_go" />
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

This solution provided by Anfurny does not work:

```
post.PostItems.Add("login", "input_go");
```

I have updated code, the button that submits has only id defined.

**EDIT2:**

I have found a good example of a page with two forms. [phpMyAdmin demo](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/index.php), it has two forms, one is for selecting different language, the other is for login. This demo has:

- username = root
- password is empty

Now I have tried to login programmatically with this code (it uses class that I have posted the link on start of the page):

```
// First we create an instance of a class PostSubmitter.
PostSubmitter post = new PostSubmitter();

// We set the URL to which the POST should go.
post.Url = "http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/index.php";

// We add items (password and username).
post.PostItems.Add("pma_username", "root");
post.PostItems.Add("pma_password", "");

// Also tried to add to which login form should post and the
// value set to id of the submit button, no luck.
//post.PostItems.Add("login_form", "input_go");

// Here we set the method.
post.Type = PostSubmitter.PostTypeEnum.Post;

// Getting back the result.
string result = post.Post();

// Writting it to the file.
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:/response.txt");
tw.WriteLine(result);
tw.Close();
```

The response.txt file has the same content as the login page, where it should have the code of the welcome page. Now how can I change code, to successfully login?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you have multiple forms posting to the same place, that you would differentiate them with the button that was clicked. Can you not do the same and add a virtual button (action) to your post list of values?

Comment: Nope, does not work as I have explained in the upper comment.

Comment: Odd. You have logged all Request.Form values to a logger or file to see what is coming through? Sorry I am little confused about your button problem. I do not think your actual form in your question has anything to do with what the C# form post class is posting. If for some weird reason it does. Add a NAME attribute to the button. Id does not get posted.

Comment: Cannot change the content of a page, so adding a name attribute to the button is not possible. I have printed the returned string into txt file, it actually returns the source code of the page, but it should return the source code with error attached with it (wrong inserted data). So it seems the request is not being send correctly.

Comment: Are you certain it is POSTING?

Comment: How can I check what is being send to the page? Maybe Wireshark?

Comment: Ok I have added example on the first page with code that I am trying to login.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something like this:

```
post.PostItems.Add("FORM_NAME","SUBMIT_BUTTON_NAME ");
```

?

Where FORM_NAME is the name of the form you wish to submit, and SUBMIT_BUTTON_NAME is the name of the submit button you wish to pretend was pressed (if more than one is present).

Comment: I have tried this, but no success. The input is defined like this: <input value="Go" type="submit" id="input_go" />. It has no name, but it has id, so I tried this: post.PostItems.Add("login", "input_go"). But as I said it did not work.